# Is the physics of semiconductors explained by nearly free electron model or is there a better model

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I am learning (independently) about semiconductors and the physics behind their properties.

Is the current 'accepted' theory for the physics of semiconductors (Electronic band structure)  based on the nearly free electron model or is there any other competing theory which explains semiconductors better (for example Tight binding model, KKR model, Density-functional theory)

Comment: The appropriate and necessary model is used as needed. Understand Ashcroft & Mermin, and move on from there as needed...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-interacting electrons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544528/non-interacting-electrons) Also: [Why Drude/Sommerfeld models even work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/648354/247642)

Comment: Further to @JonCuster's point:  [All models are wrong but some are useful.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong)